# Linux RPC - server side

Tags: linux

I am reading about RPC at [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html) page.

I understand that this a client/server model, and the server can respond to queries by the client. What I want to ask is that is it possible for a server side component to be not running when the client side tries to use RPC to invoke it, and somehow the server side is run to process the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two ways to have a system that does this:

1. The kernel does the RPC service. This is mostly true for NFS servers. The Linux kernel does the NFS service. You won't see much, if any of a user process. Part of the reason for this is performance (and NFS service is performance critical) and part is that the kernel has information about files and file systems that isn't available anywhere else.
2. You can have an "[internet super server](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node125.html)" running, that listens on a set of TCP and/or UDP ports.  When some data comes in on one of members of the set of ports, the "super server" starts the real server process, and hands off the socket as stdin and stdout. The original `inetd` has fallen way out of favor and there's [a number of replacements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd#inetd_replacements), including `xinetd`, `systemd` and others.